# Angular properties becoming undefined after initialization/onInit functions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a weird issue where properties on an angular component I have setup are losing their values after initialization.
The component is just a simple html file with a video player on it. (as per below)

```
<video width="200" controls="true" poster="" id="video">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Then in the components typescript file i've tried creating the property with a predefined value, creating it with no value and then assigning it in the constructor, and then also creating with no value and assigning in the onInit. In all three cases i can see it has the correct value if i console log the value. However in an event called later, the value is undefined. The property has not been bound to any elements or anything like that either.

**Create properties with value**

```
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  timeStarted = 0;
  timePlayed = 0;
  duration = 0;
  video: HTMLVideoElement;

  constructor() {
    
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Have values when logged here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);
    this.video = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById("video");

    this.video.addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying);
    

  }
  
  videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    //is undefined here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);
  }
}
```

**Create properties then assign in constructor**

```
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  timeStarted: number;
  timePlayed: number;
  duration: number;
  video: HTMLVideoElement;

  constructor() {
    this.timeStarted = 0;
    this.timePlayed = 0;
    this.duration = 0
    this.video = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById("video");
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    //Have values when logged here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);

    this.video.addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying);
    

  }

  videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    //is undefined here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);
  }

}
```

**Create properties then assign in onInit**

```
export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  timeStarted: number;
  timePlayed: number;
  duration: number;
  video: HTMLVideoElement;

  constructor() {
    
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.timeStarted = 0;
    this.timePlayed = 0;
    this.duration = 0
    this.video = <HTMLVideoElement> document.getElementById("video");
    //Have values when logged here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);

    this.video.addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying);
    

  }

  videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    //is undefined here
    console.log("Time Started: " + this.timeStarted);
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);
  }

}
```

Could anyone please provide any insight on what might be causing the value to disappear after initialization and loading?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you should use the `@viewChild` decorator to access elements in the view natively, instead of `document.getElementById`? It will probably work better

Answer (score 1):

This is because the key word `this` does not refer to your component `VideoPlayerComponent` as you might think, in your case it is gonna be referring to `this.video`.
Because of the following line of code:

```
this.video.addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying);
```

The function `videoStoppedPlaying` is invoked inside the object `video` and as you way or may not know the keyword `this` refers to the object where he actually is called in, thus reffering to `video`.
Inside `video` object there is no `timeStarted` and no `timePlayed` propery and that is why they are undefined, but there is a property called `duration` and that is why you get a value for `duration`.
If you want to know more about the properties that exists inside `video` object check this [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) and go HTML Audio/Video Properties.
I also created [a live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bq6t8d?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you with one more property.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be using `addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying);`
But use the `(pause)` event in the HTML template instead.

Like this:

```
<video width="200" controls="true" poster="" id="video" (pause)="videoStoppedPlaying($event)">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Your mistake here is that you didn't bind `this`. You can probably do:
`this.video.addEventListener("pause", this.videoStoppedPlaying.bind(this));`

Also, please consider using `@ViewChild()` instead of `document.getElementById("video")`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the video "event" to get all the data you need and assign it to the properties you created

your VideostoppedPlaying Function can look like this

```
    videoStoppedPlaying(event) {
    this.duration = event.target.duration
    this.timePlayed = event.target.currentTime
    console.log("Time Played: " + this.timePlayed);
    console.log("Duration: " + this.duration);
  }
}
```

And dont forget to add "event" when youre calling the function at the addEventListener

```
    this.video.addEventListener("pause",e=> this.videoStoppedPlaying(e));
```