# NgbModal injection return undefined

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying yo use a modal and retrieve data from the modal in my component.

I have the following code:

```
export class MainComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  openModal(newData: string) {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalComponent)

    modalRef.componentInstance.data= newData
  }
}
```

whenever I trigger this openModal function with a button, I noticed that this.modalService is undefined.

I checked if bootstrap is well installed and I can use any other component from bootstrap.

What am I missing there ?

Comment: Have you imported and provided NgbModal in your module ?

Comment: I have imported it in my component but not in my module. When I add it to the imports array I get the error "'NgbModal' does not appear to be an NgModule class."

Comment: Try to import the module: NgbModalModule

Comment: I have just tested and I get the same result, this.modalService is still undefined

Answer (score 0):

I'm calling my openModal function by passing it as a prop to another component. As a consequence, the keyword this is no more a reference to my MainComponent but to my ChildComponent and therefore there is no modalService in my ChildComponent.

Thanks @Elmehdi for his answer in the thread [Angular properties becoming undefined after initialization/onInit functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65021139/angular-properties-becoming-undefined-after-initialization-oninit-functions)